# Stacked box plot from indicator variables

Tags: r, ggplot2

I have a dataframe which looks like this

```
> moviesInMostPopGenres[1, ]
      drama comedy short romance action crime thriller documentary
1         0      0     0       1      0     0        0           1         
  Runtime
1      70
```

What I would like to produce is a stacked box plot where on the y axis we have genres and on the x axis we have runtime.

I can do something similar if Genre was a single column like this

```
ggplot(df, aes(as.factor(Genre), Runtime)) + geom_boxplot() +
coord_flip() +
scale_x_discrete("Genre")
```

but the difficulty is that each row can have a value for multiple genres and the genres are spread over indicator variables.

In the above example, the movie would belong to the "romance" distribution as well as the "documentary" distribution both with a runtime of 70.

Answer (score 3):

Here's an approach using ggplot2 that generates the box plots by genre groupings (using the data set provided by @neilfws) along with genre markers and a bar plot with the counts by genre set:

```
library(ggplot2)
library(ggstance)
library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)
library(egg)  # devtools::install.github("baptiste/egg") 

# Add a data column listing the genres to which each movie belongs.
# This will become the y-coordinate for all of the plots.
movies$set = apply(movies %>% select(Drama:Documentary), 1, function(x) {
  paste(sort(names(x)[which(x == 1)]), collapse="-")
})

# Add a "None" genre
movies$None=ifelse(movies$set=="", 1, 0)
movies$set[movies$set==""] = "None"

# Get order of genre groupings by median run time
set_order = movies %>% group_by(set) %>% 
  summarise(med_run = median(Runtime),
            n = n()) %>% 
  arrange(med_run) %>% 
  mutate(set = factor(set, levels=set))

# Set order of genre groupings
movies = movies %>% 
  mutate(set = factor(set, levels=set_order$set))
```

Now create and lay out three plots:

```
# Set theme elements that will apply to all future plots
theme_set(theme_classic() + 
            theme(axis.title.y=element_blank(),
                  axis.text.y=element_blank()))

# Box plot of run times by set
p1 = ggplot(movies, aes(Runtime, set)) +
  geom_boxploth() +
  coord_cartesian(xlim=c(60,240)) +
  scale_x_continuous(breaks=seq(0,300,60)) +
  theme(axis.line.y=element_blank(),
        axis.ticks.y=element_blank(),
        plot.margin=margin(r=-2))

# Plot number of movies in each set
p2 = ggplot(set_order, aes(n, set)) +
  geom_barh(stat='identity') +
  geom_text(aes(label=ifelse(n>50,n,""), x=0.5*n), colour="white", size=2.5) +
  scale_x_continuous(expand=c(0,0), limits=c(0, 1.02*max(set_order$n))) +
  theme(plot.margin=margin(r=10),
        axis.line.y=element_line(colour="grey70"),
        axis.ticks.y=element_blank()) 

# Plot genres to which each set belongs
p3 = movies %>% 
  gather(key, value, Drama:Documentary) %>% 
  group_by(set, key, value) %>% 
  slice(1) %>% 
  ungroup %>% 
  mutate(key = factor(key)) %>% 
  ggplot(aes(key, set)) +
  geom_tile(aes(fill=factor(value)), colour="white", size=0.5) +
  geom_text(aes(label=ifelse(value==1, substr(key,1,2), "")), colour="white", size=2.3) +
  theme(axis.text.x=element_text(angle=-90, hjust=0, vjust=0.5),
        axis.title.x=element_blank()) +
  scale_fill_manual(values=c("grey90", "grey30")) +
  guides(fill=FALSE)

ggarrange(p1, p3, p2, ncol=3, widths=c(5,3,5))
```

[image]

If you want to change the order, for example, to order by number of films in each genre set, just do reset the ordering:

```
# Get order of genre groupings by median run time
set_order = movies %>% group_by(set) %>% 
  summarise(med_run = median(Runtime),
            n = n()) %>% 
  arrange(n) %>% 
  mutate(set = factor(set, levels=set))

# Set order of genre groupings
movies = movies %>% 
  mutate(set = factor(set, levels=set_order$set))
```

Then run the same plot code as above to get this:

[image]

Answer (score 2):

One solution to this is the [UpSetR package](https://github.com/hms-dbmi/UpSetR). It comes with a movies dataset which is very similar to yours, as shown in [this documentation](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/UpSetR/vignettes/attribute.plots.html).

```
library(UpSetR)
library(dplyr)

# load the example movies dataset
movies <- read.csv(system.file("extdata", "movies.csv", package = "UpSetR"), 
                   header=T, sep=";")

# make it look more like your example
# first column should be movie name, the rest attributes

movies <- movies %>% select(Name, Drama, Comedy, Romance, 
                            Action, Crime, Thriller, Documentary)

# Add a Runtime column
set.seed(123)
movies <- movies %>% 
  mutate(Runtime = sample(60:240, nrow(.), replace = TRUE))

# upset
upset(movies, boxplot.summary = c("Runtime"), nsets = 7)
```

[image]

The top bar chart shows the intersections and their sizes. Below that is a chart which indicates the intersecting genres. Underneath is the boxplot of `Runtime` for each intersection.